# AUCTeX error with utf8 package recognizing " \%CW"

Tags: unicode, auctex, listingsutf8

I'm in AUCTeX in a 32-bit Win7 machine. When compiling the master file with pdflatex I'm getting the error msg given below. Can you help me understand the error and correct it?

> ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:è\itemS not set up for
>   use with LaTeX.
>
> --- TeX said ---
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.12 \item  S
>          crivi l'eqz di $\%CW$
> ```
>
> --- HELP --- No help available

Here are 2 MWE:

```
%%master.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath} %palatino font 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} 
\chead{}
\rhead{\leftmark} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts, xfrac}
\usepackage{esdiff}

\title{Mat. Sc.}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage

%\input{Capitoli/part1}
\input{Capitoli/L7}
%\input{Capitoli/domEsami}

\end{document}
```

Extract of L7.tex

```
\section{Lez.07 -- Stategie di rinforzo, incrudimento, annealing}
\label{sec-1}
\subsection{Domande}
\label{sec-1-1}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Le 4 stategie di rinforzo sono}
\item L'incrudimento o \emph{cold work} o \emph{work hadening} è
\item Scrivi l'eqz di $\%CW$  
\item \textbf{Descrivi work-hardening (cos'è, cosa fa)}
\item Dopo \%CW ricuocere il materiale per 1h a T\ped{annealing}
  produce 
\item 3 stadi di annealing do \%CW sono 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: I'm afraid AUCTeX can't figure out accented letters (quite common) in Italian such as: à, è, é... it says it is not compatible with utf8 inputenc. How do I fix this for AUCTeX in win7?

Comment: This has nothing to do with AUCTeX. You probably have a wrong file encoding set. The bar between the buffer window and the command minibuffer should have a `U` at the far left.

Comment: It looks like è is encoded as a single byte so not utf8

Comment: Add `% -*- coding: utf-8; -*-` as first line of your .tex files.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `% -*- coding: utf-8; -*-` to both the master.tex file and the dependant file worked! I can also see the `U` at the far left corner of buffer separation bar, but I can't remember whether it wasn't there yesterday.
Thank you, folks for your help.